# git fast-import in specific branch

Tags: git, bazaar

I have some Bazaar repositories and branches which I would like to import to git.

Fast-export and fast-import works well:

`bzr fast-export ../c | git fast-import`

Unfortunately this does not support branches at all. I even try to change the current branch before running `fast-import` it still imports in `master`.

How can I import my Bazaar repositories and keep the same branches on git?

Answer (score 0):

Read [the doc](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/fastimport-plugin.html#fast-export) is better: `bzr fast-export ../c --git-branch=c | git fast-import`